# Rocketchat running in docker after Nginx reverse proxy throws blank screen

Tags: javascript, nginx, meteor, reverse-proxy, rocket.chat

I have a rocketchat running well when I access it directly (i.e via docker port). But while trying to access from nginx as reverse proxy, I am getting blank page. Any idea what is wrong here?

I have used official configurations for both the nginx and docker-compose from rocketchat website.

Nginx config:

```
# Upstreams
upstream backend {
    server localhost:3000;
}

# Redirect Options
server {
  listen 80;
#  server_name 172.16.1.22;
  server_name rc.rage;
  # enforce https
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS Server
server {
    listen 443;
    #server_name 172.16.1.22;
    server_name rc.rage;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/rocketchat.access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/rocket-chat.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/rocket-chat.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # don’t use SSLv3 ref: POODLE

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
        proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Docker Compose:

```
version: '2'

services:
  rocketchat:
    image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/rocketchat
      - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/local
      - MAIL_URL=smtp://smtp.email
#      - HTTP_PROXY=http://rc.rage
#      - HTTPS_PROXY=http://rc.rage
      - Accounts_UseDNSDomainCheck=flase
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend:rocketchat"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule:Host: your.domain.tld"

  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
     - ./data/db:/data/db
     #- ./data/dump:/dump
    command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0 --storageEngine=mmapv1
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable:false"

  # this container's job is just run the command to initialize the replica set.
  # it will run the command and remove himself (it will not stay running)
  mongo-init-replica:
    image: mongo:3.2
    command: 'mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval "rs.initiate({ _id: ''rs0'', members: [ { _id: 0, host: ''localhost:27017'' } ]})"'
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  # hubot, the popular chatbot (add the bot user first and change the password before starting this image)
  hubot:
    image: rocketchat/hubot-rocketchat:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - ROCKETCHAT_URL=rocketchat:3000
      - ROCKETCHAT_ROOM=GENERAL
      - ROCKETCHAT_USER=bot
      - ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD=botpassword
      - BOT_NAME=bot
  # you can add more scripts as you'd like here, they need to be installable by npm
      - EXTERNAL_SCRIPTS=hubot-help,hubot-seen,hubot-links,hubot-diagnostics
    depends_on:
      - rocketchat
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable:false"
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/home/hubot/scripts
  # this is used to expose the hubot port for notifications on the host on port 3001, e.g. for hubot-jenkins-notifier
    ports:
      - 3001:8080

  #traefik:
  #  image: traefik:latest
  #  restart: unless-stopped
  #  command: traefik --docker --acme=true --acme.domains='your.domain.tld' --acme.email='your@email.tld' --acme.entrypoint=https --acme.storagefile=acme.json --defaultentrypoints=http --defaultentrypoints=https --entryPoints='Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https' --entryPoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS.Certificates:'
  #  ports:
  #    - 80:80
  #    - 443:443
  #  volumes:
  #    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

in 
  location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend/;

instead of backend just write your pulic ip and port

location / {
        proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:3000;